# Load javascript within JFrame or JPanel

Tags: java, javascript, swing, htmlunit

I would like to load a the below javascript code to a `JPanel` or a `JFrame`. Is it possible?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//javascript code
</script>
```

Comment: The `language` attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.  See the [HTML 4 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use third-party libraries: such as [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.

**Example:**

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class JavaScriptProgram
{
    private WebClient webClient;
    private HtmlPage currentPage;

    public JavaScriptProgram()
    {
        webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    public void visitPage(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Cannot get the page
        }
    }

    public void executeJavaScript(String code)
    {
        currentPage.executeJavaScript(code);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptProgram p = new JavaScriptProgram();
        p.visitPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        p.executeJavaScript("document.write('Hello World!');");
    }
}
```

Comment: @JessyJameson I added an example of how to execute JavaScript code in Java using HtmlUnit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want browser capability within your Swing app, you could check [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp), it supports Javascript too.

Answer (score 1):

Swing components doesn't support Javascript codes natively. If you really need integrate Javascript and Java, you can try [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). But remember: it's javascript language only, you cannot use browser's API.