# open a web link in java netbeans

Tags: java

I want to open a web page after clicking a button. I have a button and a text field. in that text field i type a web address. then i click the button.after that i want to show the result in my frame. is this possible? is there a component in palette to do so? .can i open a web page in java frame instead of opening in a browser. If it's impossible please guide me to open a web page in chrome or IE using java in net beans. Thanks in advance.

i tried this in event of button .

```
 try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.exec("C:\Users\K-9\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am i in a correct path.?

Comment: *Am I in a correct path?* No since you're executing the Chrome browser directly, and what's worse you're assuming that Chrome is installed in C:\Users\K-9\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\ path for every pc. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10601676/1065197

Comment: @user919860. i just want to show a web page in my project instead of opening a browser.

Comment: The link in my comment with the *Related* word before means *hey! this Q/A is related to what you're looking for*. Have you at least go into it and read the contents?

Comment: This link might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548459/load-javascript-within-jframe-or-jpanel

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza.this is just for me in my computer,so the path is same.thanks for the link.it helped me very much.thanks again.

Comment: I personally don't like how code3h is trying to run a web browser externally like that.  Unless it's necessary, I don't think that you should make it a habit of trying to get your work done in an external application.

Comment: No problem, code3h. :).  But, I think that Luiggi Mendoza's post might provide a simpler solution.  The one that I provided allows you to execute JavaScript, but if your goal is only to show a web page, then I think that the solution in his comment should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use java you need to escape back slashes. This code perfectly works for me:

```
    String fileName="test.html";
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe file:///C:/temp/" + fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: put the path in a properties file to get more felxibility

Answer (score 1):

1 .I have made a new project in that I have selected a new frame and drag a button from the swing controls to your frame.

2. In the buttons action event type the following code

   String url="www.google.com";

   java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
3. Then run the project

And you can also follow this tutorial

[Open a web link in java netbeans](http://tut.julfi.com/open-a-web-page-using-java-netbeans/)